# Loading Feed Properly (Parse & Swift)

Tags: swift, parse-platform, loading

I am having a feed having trouble figuring out the best way to get the objects to load the feed of my app. **My main concern is the speed of each one if the current user is following a lot of people.** I have two ways of doing:

1) I have integrated Realm.io to save the userIds of the people the current user is following on their phone. So when I want to load the feed, I just put all the followers in an array and query from that array. Code:

```
        let followingsResultsFromRealm = realm.objects(Following.self)
        //append followings to an array
        for followingResult in followingsResultsFromRealm {
            followingsArray.append(followingResult.followingObjectId)
        }
        if let currentUser = PFUser.current()?.objectId{
            followingsArray.append(currentUser)
        }

        let activityQuery = PFQuery(className: "Activity")
        activityQuery.whereKey("user", containedIn: followingsArray)
        activityQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
        activityQuery.limit = 15
        activityQuery.findObjectsInBackground....
```

2) Query for all the people the user is following then query their post from the previous query. I have a problem with this one as this way because I can not get the post from the user because their not following themselves. Code:

```
            let followQuery = PFQuery(className: "Follow")
            followQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.objectId ?? String())
            followQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")

            let activityQuery = PFQuery(className: "Activity")
            activityQuery.whereKey("user", matchesKey: "following", in: followQuery)                
            activityQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
            activityQuery.limit = 15
            activityQuery.findObjectsInBackground....
```

Which way will not cause the app to be slow when the user is following a lot of people? Or is there a way that's better that I did not put? PLEASE let me know!